# How do I convert between Drake's PointCloud and Open3D's PointCloud types

Tags: drake, open3d

I have a Drake [PointCloud](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1perception_1_1_point_cloud.html) object. This could be obtained, for instance, from a Drake simulation which includes a simulated [RgbdSensor](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1sensors_1_1_rgbd_sensor.html) and uses [DepthImageToPointCloud](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1perception_1_1_depth_image_to_point_cloud.html). I want to convert it to an [o3d.geometry.PointCloud](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/python_api/open3d.geometry.PointCloud.html) so that I can use Open3D tools to process it. How do I convert between the two types?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods to do the basic conversion:

```
def drake_cloud_to_open3d(cloud):
    indices = np.all(np.isfinite(cloud.xyzs()), axis=0)

    pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
    pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(cloud.xyzs()[:, indices].T)

    if cloud.has_rgbs():
        pcd.colors = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(cloud.rgbs()[:, indices].T
                                                / 255.)


def open3d_cloud_to_drake(cloud):
    fields = BaseField.kXYZs
    if cloud.has_colors():
        fields |= BaseField.kRGBs

    drake_cloud = PointCloud(new_size=len(cloud.points), fields=Fields(fields))
    drake_cloud.mutable_xyzs()[:] = np.asarray(cloud.points).T

    if cloud.has_colors():
        drake_cloud.mutable_rgbs()[:] = np.asarray(cloud.colors).T

    return drake_cloud
```

Both types also support normals; those could be handled similarly.